# Upgraded Ubuntu Server to 13.04, but still announces new release

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I upgraded my Ubuntu Server 12.10 to 13.04 a couple of days ago, using "do-release-upgrade"

But every time I log in, I still get this message:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 13.04 (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-19-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

New release '13.04' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the [MOTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motd_%28Unix%29) and it seems it didn't update properly. You're [not the only one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138991) with that problem though.

Try removing the following file, which tells Ubuntu that there is an upgrade available:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available
```

After doing that, you should call the following script to update the MOTD. Ubuntu will check for the existence of the file we just deleted and therefore won't show you that there's a pending upgrade anymore:

```
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd
```

Comment: That helped thanks! Another funny thing is, that my bash prompt still shows the ole version: carsten@Ubuntu-1210-quantal-64-minimal:~$ but i can live with that

Comment: Hm. What does `echo $PS1` say? Maybe still an old `/etc/hostname` you're using?

Comment: It was indeed the hostname :-) Thanks